# How can I split these <td tags from BeautifulSoup on Python?

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website and I am having a difficult time understanding.

I am trying to split the tag into two groups so when I run a for loop it should be:

```
# Group 1
<td class="right endpoint tooltip" data-endpoint="/players/pgl_cum_stats.cgi?player=adebaba01&amp;year=2023&amp;date_game=2022-10-19&amp;is_playoff_game=N" data-stat="game_season"><strong>1</strong></td>
<td class="left" data-stat="date_game"><a href="/boxscores/202210190MIA.html">2022-10-19</a></td>
<td class="right" data-stat="age">25-093</td>
<td class="left" data-stat="team_id"><a href="/teams/MIA/2023.html">MIA</a></td>
<td class="center iz" data-stat="game_location"></td>
<td class="left" data-stat="opp_id"><a href="/teams/CHI/2023.html">CHI</a></td>
<td class="center" csk="-8" data-stat="game_result">L (-8)</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="gs">1</td>
<td class="right" csk="2040" data-stat="mp">34:00</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fg">5</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fga">15</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fg_pct">.333</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3">0</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3a">0</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3_pct"></td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ft">2</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fta">3</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ft_pct">.667</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="orb">1</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="drb">8</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="trb">9</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ast">2</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="stl">0</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="blk">1</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="tov">5</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="pf">4</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="pts">12</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="game_score">1.7</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="plus_minus">-15</td>

# Group 2
<td class="right endpoint tooltip" data-endpoint="/players/pgl_cum_stats.cgi?player=adebaba01&amp;year=2023&amp;date_game=2022-10-21&amp;is_playoff_game=N" data-stat="game_season"><strong>2</strong></td>
<td class="left" data-stat="date_game"><a href="/boxscores/202210210MIA.html">2022-10-21</a></td>
<td class="right" data-stat="age">25-095</td>
<td class="left" data-stat="team_id"><a href="/teams/MIA/2023.html">MIA</a></td>
<td class="center iz" data-stat="game_location"></td>
<td class="left" data-stat="opp_id"><a href="/teams/BOS/2023.html">BOS</a></td>
<td class="center" csk="-7" data-stat="game_result">L (-7)</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="gs">1</td>
<td class="right" csk="2093" data-stat="mp">34:53</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fg">8</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fga">11</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fg_pct">.727</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3">0</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3a">0</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="fg3_pct"></td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ft">3</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="fta">4</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ft_pct">.750</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="orb">3</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="drb">5</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="trb">8</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="ast">5</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="stl">2</td>
<td class="right iz" data-stat="blk">0</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="tov">5</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="pf">4</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="pts">19</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="game_score">16.6</td>
<td class="right" data-stat="plus_minus">+20</td>
```

I will then put these two groups into a 2D list.

I hope that makes sense. Any help or feedback will be greatly appreciated!

I tried:

```
stats = player_header.find_all('td')
for stat in stats:
    print (stat.text)
```

But I cannot group or break these tags into separate groups.

Comment: Are these tags inside `<tr>` (row)? You can split it by this row then.

Comment: What's the original website look like? What data do you use to group the `td` tags?

Comment: Is there other HTML on the page, or is this everything?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Do you think my below answer makes sense?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes! how would you split per row? would it be stats = player_header.find_all('tr')?

Comment: @FruitBoy I've deleted and then undelete my answer, so you might not see it in your inbox

Comment: @MendelG Based on previous comment, there are `<tr>` tags, so it's simple table scraping :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yeah, I see that now :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes that the only HTML is what you have shared (`html_doc` is you above HTML).

Here's the approach, [`insert_before()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#insert-before-and-insert-after) a new *wrapper* `class` before each group, the group is based on the class `right endpoint tooltip`, and then create two lists accordingly.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

out1 = []
out2 = []
for tag in soup.find_all("td", class_="right endpoint tooltip"):
    tag.insert_before(soup.new_tag("div", **{"class": "wrapper"}))


for tag in soup.find_all(class_="right endpoint tooltip")[0].find_all_next():

    if "wrapper" in tag.attrs.get("class", []):
        break
    out1.append(tag.text)

for tag in soup.find_all(class_="right endpoint tooltip")[1].find_all_next():
    out2.append(tag.text)
```